# Jquery submit() function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

Here's my code:

```
function checkupload(){
if(upload == false)
{
    alert("Please upload a file");
    return false;
}
(...)
$('#download_form').submit();
 alert('submitted');
}

My HTML:

<form action="http://localhost/rendu/download.php" method="post" id="download_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="57" id="in_57"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="72" id="in_72"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="png" id="in_png"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ico" id="in_ico"/>

<a onclick='checkupload()'><img src="images/download_normal.png" onmouseover="mover()" onmouseout="mout()"/></a>
</form>
```

No matter what I do the form won't get submitted. I've taken a look at the requests and there's no request sent to the download.php page, but the alert message is displayed.

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: it's defined earlier in the code. There is no error in the console.

Comment: jsfiddle from cljk answer below ( http://jsfiddle.net/FXd8p/ ) reproduces your code, and the form submits. So there must be something else we are not aware of.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome Version 23.0.1255.0 (154635)

Answer (score 2):

You mixed up two things: binding to the event-handler and calling the form submission.

Compare
http://jsfiddle.net/FXd8p/

and
http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: I think you're right. Then how can I submit a form from JavaScript?

Comment: Your current version (using submit()) should work - but check the console. Perhaps "upload" (line 2) is not defined elsewhere and the script fails.

Answer (score 1):

Call submit without putting alert into it.

```
$('#download_form').submit();
```

Comment: That's what I did on the first place but the result is the same.

Comment: @Adil: nobody's going to be able to visit a site on your localhost.

Comment: Yes I made another html page which works fine with this code:  <form action="http://localhost/rendu/download.php" method="post">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

Comment: Yes true @calvinf, I just want to make sure he has the valid url.